# Bottom line of navigation bar or Top line of toolbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, line, toolbar

I want to ask the line is

"**Bottom line of navigation bar**" or "**Top line of toolbar**" ?

[image]

I really want to remove this line.....

But I try a lot of method and they are not working at all

I use the lib from this to show the view

https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

(bty, I already removed the code of lib where is drawing top line)

```
// Draw top line
bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(rect), 0.0)];
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:197.0/255.0 alpha:0.75] setStroke];
[bezierPath setLineWidth:1.0];
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Thanks for your help !!

-

**[ADD]**

I change the position of toolbar from his lib

if add 0.5 -> gray line

if add 1   -> white blank

```
CGRect frame = self.tabsView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0.0;
frame.origin.y = [self.tabLocation boolValue] ? topLayoutGuide+0.5 : CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - [self.tabHeight floatValue];
frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
frame.size.height = [self.tabHeight floatValue];
self.tabsView.frame = frame;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/shadowImage

Comment: I will suggest you temporary solution. I know it is not exact solution but you  can solve your problem with this. Add view on that line & give the colour to the view view same as colour of your navigation bar

Comment: try to adjust your tableview upside/downside

Comment: i think it is separator between view and navigation bar. you need to manually adjust it. :)

Comment: make sure your tabbar's y position should be 64

Comment: I separator the bars , but it still has something there ...

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me in advance for I am to use Swift language. 
That being said, let's get done to business!

To remove the bottom line of a navigationBar, you must remove the shadowImage and the backgroundImage

Just do something like this and you'll get rid of that annoying line

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
```

I don't know if there also is a top line atop of toolbars, let me know ;)

Hope this'll help!